# Is it Possible to have Global Angular Version to have Consistent Angular Version Across Multiple Projects?

Tags: angular, docker, npm

I have multiple angular projects / libraries in different repositories. Most of which are published to NPM and then pulled into by other projects. Because of this, I need to make sure the Angular versions are consistent. Is there a way to have angular installed globally so that all my projects use the same angular version and do not need to worry about upgrades?

One of my thoughts is if you can do something along the lines of:

```
npm install -g @angular/common @angular/core, etc..
```

in a base docker image, lets say 'angular-base-test' for now. Then for my other applications to use this base image like so:

```
FROM angular-base-test

build and compile app using those global modules..
```

When I want to upgrade the version of angular, then I just need to do it in the base image and rebuild the other images to get the latest image. I think I am missing something big with this idea though.

Comment: just use monorepo style thats the most easy way. the nrwl nx package offers a lot in this case or you just setup a empty angular workplace with the cli and add the projects there afterwards.

Comment: @JohnnyDevNull I took a quick look and am not sure what the [nrwl nx](https://github.com/nrwl/nx) package solves in this case. Ideally I would like to control the angular version over many projects that may be worked on by others. How I envision it would be to externalize as many dependancies as I can to a single base docker image and the other apps use that as its base to make sure they have the same version of dependancies as others including Angular version.

Comment: and thats what nx does. you have only one node_modules folder and many apps/ in there. Also the default angular workplace works like this. You generate your own libraries to share code between them and all use the same node_modules folder. Just keep it simple. Using docker in this case is not the right way in my opinion.